# Copy-Item Could not find part of path (with . in folder name)

Tags: powershell, copy-item

I'm trying to use Copy-Item to copy a file to an existing folder and getting the error "Could not find part of path". I've Googled this problem for ages, but can't seem to find an answer.

I altered the code to check that I could copy to each folder in the path and then hit the problem when .'s were used in the file name. Also I cannot change the folder name because the folder name is created by a (crappy) Oracle related installer.

Essentially the code is like this (the code is run in the context of the source directory)...

```
$Filename = "new.txt"
$Destination = "C:\a\b\c\d\e.f\g\h"
Copy-Item -Path $Filename -Destination $Destination
```

So this works for folders a,b,c and d, but for folder e.f new.txt is copied to folder d and renamed to e.f (which makes sense) and for folders g and h I get the above error. How do I get Copy-Item to see e.f as a folder?

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: I don`t really get what the problem is. The lines you posted works perfect for me. The "new.txt" file is getting copied to "C:\a\b\c\d\e.f\g\h"

Do all directories exist before starting the "Copy-Item" command?

Answer (score 0):

Create the directory first:
New-Item -Path d:\a\b\c\d\e.f\g\h -type directory

Answer (score -1):

You can force `Copy-Item` to see the destination as a folder by appending a backslash:

```
Copy-Item -Path $Filename -Destination ($Destination + '\')
```

Comment: This does not work in this instance, the same error occurs. The fact that C:\a\b\c\d\e.f\g\h doesn't kind of indicates this as e.f does have a \ after it. Appending \ to the end of e.f, g or h makes no difference in my tests.

Comment: Please provide your full code. `Copy-Item` to an existing destination ``C:\a\b\c\d\e.f\g\h\`` works as described. If it doesn't work for you you're doing something different from what you said.

Comment: For all intents and purposes, the code is exactly the same except the problem folder actually has two .'s in it, so the path is more like C:\a\b\c\d\11.2.0\g\h

Comment: Time to fess up apparently I can;t tell the difference between 1's and l's (they are kinda similar).

Comment: So the issue was caused by a mistyped path and is now resolved?

Answer (score -1):

What you have works fine.  The only thing I had to do to make is work was remove the $ from the $copy-item line.

Comment: Well done for spotting the deliberate mistake! Unfortunately the mistake is only in this forum, my script that is failing fine $ wise.

Comment: Time to fess up, the $ wasn't the issue. Apparently I can't tell the difference between 1's and l's (they are kinda similar).

Answer (score -1):

Create the directory first.  This is not an issue.

```
$Filename = "new.txt"
$Destination = "C:\a\b\c\d\e.f\g\h"
mkdir $Destination
Copy-Item -Path $Filename -Destination $Destination
```